# Python Threading - Stop the other threads

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

1. I trigger an event from a custom tool and I have 4 linux servers where I need to monitor logs and grep for a particular event ID.
2. The event ID  could occur in any ONE of the 4 servers.
3. I wrote a method that will make a ssh session checks for the grep pattern. Since there could be many servers added, I used a threading module to look concurrently in all the servers a specified time.
4. If the match is found in one server, I want other threads to die. Is there a way I can inform to other threads to stop searching if the pattern is found in one? Is it safe?

I have many of these kind of functionality to be verified in many servers. So, I do not want to waste any time doing it in serially and want to save memory by stopping other threads.

Comment: related: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/4279)

Comment: How are you invoking ssh?  Are you using a library like `paramiko`?  Showing the relevant part of your code would be helpful.

Comment: Why not fork and use subprocesses?  Then you can kill the subprocesses.